# Bootstrap 4 card-Image-overlay text flowing out of image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have this image with text overlayed, Not sure what causing it, but on mobile (small/xs)the play button and title is getting out of the image due the p text being long. what bootstrap class am i messing up to cause this issue? I thought the image height will adjust to take care of this issue when texts inside gets longer, is it the image?.

[image]

```css
html {
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1400px;
 }
}
h1, .h1 {
  font-size: 3.815rem;
}
h2, .h2 {
  font-size: 2.441rem;
}
h3, .h3 {
  font-size: 1.563rem;
}
h4, .h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.product-video-section .product-video-container {
  position: relative;
}
.product-video-section .product-video-container video {
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
.product-video-section .product-video-container #product-video-button {
  color: #d4272e;
}
.product-video-section .product-video-container .product-video {
  display: none;
}
.product-video-section .product-video-container .product-video-texts .play-btn-wrap {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d4272e;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
  color: #d4272e;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.product-video-section .product-video-container .product-video-texts .play-btn-wrap i {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.product-video-section .product-video-container .product-video-texts .play-btn-wrap:hover {
  background-color: #d4272e;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.product-video-section .product-video-container .product-video-texts .play-btn-wrap:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./Library/bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.2.2/dist/ionicons.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Library/bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Library/bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css" />

    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/index.css">


</head>

<body>
    
        <div class="product-video-section ">
            <div class="product-video-container card">
                <img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x8p2z5cvip5u38/chicago.jpg?dl=1">
                <div class="card-img-overlay  d-flex align-items-center product-video-texts text-dark" id="">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
                                    <h4 class="card-title ">This is video</h4>
                                    <p class="card-text ">
                                        
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint dolore nemo deserunt voluptatum animi omnis corrupti nam recusandae aliquam, amet ullam qui sequi assumenda, eius, debitis iusto voluptas perferendis!
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint dolore nemo deserunt voluptatum animi omnis corrupti nam recusandae aliquam, amet ullam qui sequi assumenda, eius, debitis iusto voluptas perferendis! sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint dolore nemo deserunt voluptatum animi omnis corrupti nam recusandae aliquam, amet ullam qui sequi assumenda, eius, debitis iusto voluptas perferendissit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint dolore nemo deserunt voluptatum animi omnis corrupti nam recusandae aliquam, amet ullam qui sequi assumenda, eius, debitis iusto voluptas perferendis!!
                                    
                                    </p>
    
                                    <div href="" class="play-btn-wrap d-flex justify-content-center" data-toggle="modal"
                                         data-target="#@videoTarget">
                                        <i class="ion-ios-play product-video-button  align-self-center pl-1" id="" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 
 

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap card is not cutting it in this situation , with amount of content i will potentially have . I refracted to use background image instead. Here is my code

```css
html {
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1400px;
 }
}
h1, .h1 {
  font-size: 3.815rem;
}
h2, .h2 {
  font-size: 2.441rem;
}
h3, .h3 {
  font-size: 1.563rem;
}
h4, .h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.product-video-section {
  height: 35rem;
}
.product-video-section .product-video-container {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x8p2z5cvip5u38/chicago.jpg?dl=1");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}
.product-video-section .product-video-container .product-video-texts {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}
.product-video-section .product-video-container .product-video-texts .play-btn-wrap {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d4272e;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
  color: #d4272e;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.product-video-section .product-video-container .product-video-texts .play-btn-wrap i {
  color: #d4272e;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.product-video-section .product-video-container .product-video-texts .play-btn-wrap:hover {
  background-color: #d4272e;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.product-video-section .product-video-container .product-video-texts .play-btn-wrap:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {

  .product-video-texts {
      top:50% !important;
      left:40% !important;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="./Library/bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.2.2/dist/ionicons.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Library/bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Library/bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css" />

    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/index.css">


</head>

<body>
    <div class="product-video-section ">
        <div class="product-video-container">
            <div class="product-video-texts" id="">
                <div class="text-white">
                    <h4>This is video</h4>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint dolore nemo deserunt
                        voluptatum animi omnis corrupti nam recusandae aliquam, amet ullam qui sequi assumenda,
                        eius, debitis iusto voluptas perferendis!
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint dolore nemo deserunt
                        voluptatum animi omnis corrupti nam recusandae aliquam, amet ullam qui sequi assumenda,
                        eius, debitis iusto voluptas perferendis!
                    </p>

                    <div href="" class="play-btn-wrap d-flex justify-content-center" data-toggle="modal"
                        data-target="#@videoTarget">
                        <i class="ion-ios-play product-video-button  align-self-center pl-1" id="" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you happy with this or do you really want to use `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is happening is that the `div.card-img-overlay` has the following styles:

```
.card-img-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}
```

This means that as the content inside of that element gets larger (or the box itself gets smaller), the box will not expand to fit the content. This is a limitation of the Bootstrap card component, and you did nothing wrong.

Your have a couple options to fix this:

1) Limit the amount of content allowed to go inside of a card so that this never happens. To me, this is the only real solution. Based on my tests, a limit of 65 words, or roughly 675 characters seems to work across all media queries (using your current styles).

1b) Increase the height of the image. I'm not exactly sure if this would work, and you would need to coordinate this effort with my previous suggestion about limiting the text input.

2) Write Media queries to decrease the font size accordingly so that the text adjusts to fit when necessary. This is a tedious solution, but a solution nonetheless. However, no amount of styles can be written to accommodate any amount of text. You will need to still limit the amount of text which can go inside a card.

3) Use [element queries](https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries) to adjust the size of the text whenever the element gets too small. This is not much different than using CSS media queries.

4) Abandon the card component and just create a div with the image as a background. You can use the `background-size` css property to adjust how the image stretches and resizes as the element gets bigger or smaller.

Answer (score 2):

You have some competing properties at work here. On one hand, `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` are telling that `<img>` to fill the horizontal space of the `.dnow-video-container.card` (note that it maintains its natural 500px height) BUT you're absolutely positioning the `.card-img-overlay`, thus removing *its* height from the document's consideration. So the parent, `.dnow-video-container.card` is collapsing to the height of the `<img>`. A border style, or `overflow: hidden;" on`.dnow-video-container.card`, would illustrate that the`.card-img-overlay` is overflowing its parent.

A solution I've used in this predicament is to assign the image as a `background-image` of the parent, allowing the re-flowable text content to set the height of the parent.

```css
.parent {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.overlay {
  padding: 1.25rem;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" style="background-image: url('https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x8p2z5cvip5u38/chicago.jpg?dl=1')">
  <div class="overlay">
    <h4>This is video</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint dolore nemo deserunt voluptatum animi omnis corrupti nam recusandae aliquam, amet ullam qui sequi assumenda, eius, debitis iusto voluptas perferendis! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint dolore nemo deserunt voluptatum animi omnis corrupti nam recusandae aliquam, amet ullam qui sequi assumenda, eius, debitis iusto voluptas perferendis! sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint
      dolore nemo deserunt voluptatum animi omnis corrupti nam recusandae aliquam, amet ullam qui sequi assumenda, eius, debitis iusto voluptas perferendissit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint dolore nemo deserunt voluptatum animi omnis
      corrupti nam recusandae aliquam, amet ullam qui sequi assumenda, eius, debitis iusto voluptas perferendis!!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to this div ("col-lg-6 col-sm-12") class to fix it like that:

```
<style>.example { max-height: 100vh; overflow: auto; }</style>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 example">
  <h4 class="card-title ">This is video</h4>
  <p class="card-text ">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint dolore nemo deserunt voluptatum animi omnis corrupti nam recusandae aliquam, amet ullam qui sequi assumenda, eius, debitis iusto voluptas perferendis!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint dolore nemo deserunt voluptatum animi omnis corrupti nam recusandae aliquam, amet ullam qui sequi assumenda, eius, debitis iusto voluptas perferendis! sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint dolore nemo deserunt voluptatum animi omnis corrupti nam recusandae aliquam, amet ullam qui sequi assumenda, eius, debitis iusto voluptas perferendissit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia sint dolore nemo deserunt voluptatum animi omnis corrupti nam recusandae aliquam, amet ullam qui sequi assumenda, eius, debitis iusto voluptas perferendis!!                                    
  </p>
  <div href="" class="play-btn-wrap d-flex justify-content-center" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@videoTarget">
    <i class="ion-ios-play dnow-video-button  align-self-center pl-1" id="" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

read more: [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), [length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Units)

Hope that solve it and good luck!

Answer (score -1):

The content inside of that element gets larger (or the box itself gets smaller), the box will not expand to fit the content.
So i recommend to use the background-size css property to adjust how the image stretches and resizes as the element gets bigger or smaller.

```
.parent {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Beside being you can use the `<center></center>` tag and and use a css poperty `border` to make sure it's inside the box .

Comment: -1 - you copied content from another answer while providing a solution suggested by that same answer. Also, the `<center>` element is obsolete and should not be used in today's HTML.